Setting Z-index of child element less than parent wihtout hiding it
I have a parent div which has a background image (an SVG with just a diagonal line).
My child div will have some background-color depending on the value of a variable.
I want to show the parent background image (diagonal line) over my child div background colour.
Naturally, I resorted to using z-index. But it doesn't work. Setting z-index : -1 for child div hides it altogether (I think that happens because it is going behind the root div itself).
My limitation is I cannot position both the parent or child divs as absolute, otherwise my layout would go for a toss (positioning them as relative for z-index to take effect)
<div style="background-image:url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20version%3D'1.1'%20preserveAspectRatio%3D'none'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2010%2010'%3E%20%3Cpath%20d%3D'M%2010%200%20L%200%2010'%20fill%3D'none'%20stroke%3D'black'%20stroke-width%3D'1'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E&quot;); background-color: transparent">
<div style="background-color: red; border-radius:6px"; padding: 1px; display: block;></div>
</div>


Why not swap the divs around so the background-color is on the parent, and the diagonal line is on the child? Or wrap them in a parent element (with position: relative) and then use position: absolute

"I want to show the parent background image (diagonal line) over my child div background colour." - that is not possible. The background of your child is not a "separate" thing, the background and content of the child element, are "one". If you use a pseudo element inside the inner div for the background color though, position that absolute and then specify the z-index for that.

You can use ::after to style your parent element with position absolute so it does not break your layout


.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.parent::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20version%3D'1.1'%20preserveAspectRatio%3D'none'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2010%2010'%3E%20%3Cpath%20d%3D'M%2010%200%20L%200%2010'%20fill%3D'none'%20stroke%3D'black'%20stroke-width%3D'1'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-size: cover;
  /* Adjust as necessary */
  z-index: 1;
  /* z-index 1 to make sure it overlays the child */
}

.child {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>




Another approach could be using a ::before pseudo element that will render the "background" (the svg diagonal line) in a absolute positioned manner relative to its parent container .child.
This way you can still use position: absolute but in an element defined in the css realm and that will superimpose over the .child element.
Since the .parent div is not needed anymore, I decided to remove it and show how you can apply that strategy to a single div having its own background (red) that you wish to overlay with your svg.


.child {
  position: relative;
  
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1px;
  display: block;
  
  /*crops the background taking into account the corder radius*/
  overflow: hidden; 
  
  /*here I'm giving an height otherwise since there's no content it would be zero*/
  height: 5em; 
}

.child::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20version%3D'1.1'%20preserveAspectRatio%3D'none'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2010%2010'%3E%20%3Cpath%20d%3D'M%2010%200%20L%200%2010'%20fill%3D'none'%20stroke%3D'black'%20stroke-width%3D'1'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
<div class="child"></div>



